# Kinect stops getting SkeletonFramesReady

Tags: c#, .net, windows, kinect, kinect-sdk

After some 2682-2683 frames the Kinect stops getting calls to SkeletonFramesReady.
The program doesn't crash and the UI doesn't freeze. Seems like a buffer issue or something is being called a bunch when is doesn't need to be. Does anything appear to be out of the normal?

```
  private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            bool gotData = false;

            using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {
                if (skeletonFrame != null && skeletonData != null)
                {
                    skeletonData = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletonData);
                    gotData = true;
                }
            }

            if (gotData)
            {
                using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
                {
                    // Draw a transparent background to set the render size
                    dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, DrawingToolsFactory.RenderWidth, DrawingToolsFactory.RenderHeight));

                    // Grab the first skeleton
                    Skeleton currentSkeleton = (from s in skeletonData
                                                where s.TrackingState ==
                                                                SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                                                select s).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (currentSkeleton == null) return;

                    if (currentSkeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                    {
                        this.DrawBonesAndJoints(currentSkeleton, dc);

                        Joint joint = currentSkeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderCenter];
                    }
                    else if (currentSkeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.PositionOnly)
                    {
                        dc.DrawEllipse(
                        DrawingToolsFactory.CreateCenterPointBrush(),
                        null,
                        this.SkeletonPointToScreen(currentSkeleton.Position),
                        DrawingToolsFactory.BodyCenterThickness,
                        DrawingToolsFactory.BodyCenterThickness);
                    }
                }

                // prevent drawing outside of our render area
                this.drawingGroup.ClipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, DrawingToolsFactory.RenderWidth, DrawingToolsFactory.RenderHeight));
            }
        }
    }
```